# Monitor connections in the connection pool on Sun App Server

Tags: monitoring, oracle-application-server

On a Sun (now Oracle) Application Server, how can I monitor connections in the connection pool, on a scheduled frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [monitor command](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3675/monitor-1?a=view).

You would use:

> --type
>
> connectorpool

and

> --interval  The interval in seconds before capturing monitoring
>   attributes. If the interval must be
>   greater than 0. The monitoring
>   attributes are displayed on stdout
>   until you type ctrl-c or q. The
>   default value is 30.